# Use a multiprocessing.Queue in luigi

Tags: python, resources, queue, multiprocessing, luigi

I have a set of tasks in luigi which all need to access a database. I can have up to 8 tasks accessing my database at the same time provided they are on different ports (I have the list of allowed ports).
How should I best implement this restriction which seems to be similar to the standard restriction of number of workers, ie for my case a task should run when a worker is free AND a database port is free.

I tried creating a `multiprocessing.Queue()` in `__main__` and pass this to the `WrapperTask`, which receives it as a `luigi.Parameter()`, but this gives an error and hangs

```
UserWarning: Parameter "queue" with value <multiprocessing.queues.Queue object at 0x00000000149E4518>" is not of type string.
warnings.warn('Parameter "{}" with value "{}" is not of type string.'.format(param_name, param_value))
```

The idea was that a `.get()` call would hang a Task if the queue is empty and continue once another task `.put(port)` again.

What is going wrong here? Or am I taking the completely wrong approach to managing the resource in luigi?

Answer (score 0):

You should be using "resources" section in Luigi Configuration. This will ensure that not more than this number of workers share a global resource. Find more here https://luigi.readthedocs.io/en/stable/configuration.html#resources.